# Print non used character in alphabet

Tags: c, string, alphabet

I'm trying to create a program in C that prints the letters from alphabet that are not in gussed_character. All unused letters are saved in available_character.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

void letters(const char gussed_character[], char available_character[]){
    char alphabet[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int gussed_character_lenght = strlen(gussed_character);
    int alphabet_lenght = strlen(alphabet);
    int counter = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<alphabet_lenght; i++){
        counter = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j<gussed_character_lenght; j++){
            if(alphabet[i] != gussed_character[j]){
                counter++;                              
            }
            if(counter == gussed_character_lenght){
                available_character[i] = alphabet[i];
            }           
        }
    }
    printf("%s", available_character);
}

int main(){
    char result[30];
    letters("arpstxgoieyu", result);  
}
```

Example from code:

> letters("arpstxgoieyu", result);

This letters are used and prgram should print this letters:

> bcdfhjklmnqvwz

But my program print this:

> %bcd@fPhajklmn q

Comment: `available_character[i] = alphabet[i];` You need two indexes, `i` plus another one for `available_character`.

Comment: Also, don't forget to add a string terminator `\0` to `available_character`.

Comment: And you should place that `if` with the assignment *after* the inner loop...

Comment: That `counter` appears a bit inconvenient to me, I personally would apply a `goto` in this case (I know, discussion ahead, but it appears valid to me in this case): `for(size_t i = 0; i < al; ++i) { for(size_t j = 0; j < gl; ++j) { if(a[i] == g[j]) { goto SKIP; } } av[pos++] = a[i]; SKIP:; }`

Comment: `strlen` itself needs to iterate over the string as well, which actually is unnecessary if you use pointers: `for(;*alphabet, ++alphabet) { for(char* g = guessed; *g; ++g) { if(*g == *alphabet) { goto SKIP; } } *available++ = *alphabet; SKIP:; }` – note the checks for `*xyz` (checking if terminating null character has been reached!) and how you can advance the pointers provided as parameters as you don't need them any more after the loops anyway...

Comment: Side note: Your approach is a solution with quadratic `O(n²)` effort – are the strings always *sorted*? Because if so, there's a linear (`O(n)`) solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your bug is inside this snippet:

```c
            ...

            if(counter == gussed_character_lenght){
                available_character[i] = alphabet[i];
            }

            ...
```

When you determine that indeed, `gussed_character` contains `alphabet[i]`, you try to add that character to the `available_character` array. However, you put `alphabet[i]` at position `i` in `available_character`. This means that the character inside `alphabet` at position `i` is copied to that same position in `available_character`. Notice that the output string contains the not used characters in the same position as in `alphabet`:

```c
"a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z"    // alpabet

   | | |   |   |   | | | | |
   V V V   V   V   V V V V V   

"% b c d @ f P h a j k l m n   q"                        // output string
```

Then the skipped characters are undefined, since you don't write anything to there (meaning it will take the value of whatever happens to be at that memory location at that time, making it random).

Instead of positioning the available character at position `i`, place it at the end of `available_character`. You can use a variable to keep track of the end of the `available_character` string at position `alphabet[i]` there.

I took your requirements and also implemented it myself, since I see some points where the code could also be improved (besides the bug):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void letters(const char* used_characters, char* available_characters){
    const char* alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    unsigned int available_character_index = 0;

    for (const char* alphabet_letter = alphabet; *alphabet_letter != '\0'; alphabet_letter++) {
        bool character_is_used = false;
        for (const char* used_character = used_characters; *used_character != '\0'; used_character++) {
            if (*used_character == *alphabet_letter) {
                character_is_used = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        
        if (!character_is_used) {
            available_characters[available_character_index++] = *alphabet_letter;
        }
    }
    
    available_characters[available_character_index] = '\0';
    printf("%s", available_characters);
}

int main(){
    char result[30];
    letters("arpstxgoieyu", result);  
    
    return 0;
}
```

Main takeaways are:

- Obvious one is the bug fix. I now use a variable `available_character_index` to keep track of the end of the `available_characters` string and position any available characters there, also taking care to update `available_character_index` whenever I add a character.
- You forgot to terminate the `available_characters` string. This could lead to the terminal going haywire when you print the `available_characters` string.
- I think it's conceptually easier to iterate through a string by having a char pointer that starts at the beginning of the string and works on the array till it hits `\0` (the null character). So, I changed the for-loops to work with them instead of an integer index.
- I find your use of the `counter` variable a bit confusing. From what I gather, you're incrementing it only when `alphabet[i] != gussed_character[j]`, so at the end if `gussed_characters` contains some character in `aphabet`, it should no longer be equal to `strlen(gussed_characters)`. That condition does work, but it's quite confusing. In this case, a boolean is more appropriate (simple == better).